# How to group terms?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, group-by

I want to group months together and plot it. Not sure how to approach it any help would be great.

Data:

```
Month<-c("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December")

year<-c(2020,2021)

Values<-c(29,43,75,37,89,88,45,64,24,15,26,35,78,93,86,90)
```

So I want to group Jan to Apr, May-Aug, Sep-Dec and then just plot the average of those months. I am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: create a new variable with values T1, T2 and T3, based on the months. Then use this new variable in plotting

Comment: @Wimpel There are like thousands of data and so creating 3 variables and trying to put the values in them is going to be extremely tedious.

Comment: these data don't make a data.frame. there are 16 values, 2 years and 12 months. I would suggest dput() on a small sample of the rows.

Comment: @Gokul, you misunderstood me. You want to use something like `case_when()` in combination with `%in%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `cut`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
    group_by(Month = cut(match(Month, month.name),
       breaks = c(-Inf, 4, 8, Inf), 
         labels = c('Jan - Apr', 'May - Aug', 'Sep - Dec'))) %>%
    summarise(Values = mean(Values, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Month, Values)) + 
           geom_col()
```

Comment: I am getting an error                                                                                                                 Error:Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `Month`.
x 'x' must be numeric
i Input `Month` is `cut(...)`.

Comment: @Gokul You can change it to `match` with `month.name`

Answer (score 1):

If your data is called `df` you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(Month = case_when(Month %in% month.name[1:4] ~ 'Jan - Apr', 
                             Month %in% month.name[5:8] ~ 'May - Aug', 
                             TRUE ~ 'Sep - Dec')) %>%
  summarise(Values = mean(Values, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(Month, Values) + geom_col()
```

Note that `month.name` is an inbuilt R-constant

```
month.name
#[1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"   "May"   "June"      "July"
#[8] "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December"
```

Comment: I am getting an error  Problem adding computed columns in `group_by()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `Month`.
x Input `Month` can't be recycled to size 7.
i Input `Month` is `case_when(...)`.
i Input `Month` must be size 7 or 1, not 12.